# Solving the variance of a compound pdf

Tags: integration, statistics, expected-value, variance, density-function

Before I state the question, I want to quickly point out that the question is stated using a constant $\sigma$, while also maintaining that the inner pdf $f$ is a mean 0 and variance 1 density.  It's a little confusing, but I believe that the $\sigma$ may refer to some constant and not the standard deviation of $f$.

---

Suppose the $f$ be a mean 0 density having variance 1.  What is the variance associated with the density $g(x) = f(x/\sigma)/\sigma$?

---

My progress so far is as follows:

$Var(g(x)) = E[(f(x/\sigma)/\sigma)^{2}] - E[f(x/\sigma)/\sigma]^{2}$

I believe the expected value of $g$ is
$E[g(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x/\sigma)/\sigma dx = 0 $, and by extension that $E[X]^{2} = 0$.

But I am having difficulty resolving $E[X^{2}]$.

So far I've manipulated it to resemble $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}f(x/\sigma)/\sigma dx$, and I believe I can remove $1/\sigma$ outside the integral to get $(1/\sigma) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}f(x/\sigma)dx$, but I'm uncertain how to proceed from this point.

I suspect the integration should resolve to 1, based on the fact that the question was presented to me as a multiple choice problem with $1/\sigma$ being one of the choices, but I don't know how to prove that, assuming that choice is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology you're using is confusing; I assume that there is a random variable $X$, which has a density $f_X$.  The mean of $X$ is $\operatorname{E}[X] = 0$ and the variance of $X$ is $\operatorname{Var}[X] = 1$.

The question, as I have interpreted it, is: if there is a random variable $Y$ with density $f_Y$, such that $f_Y(x) = f_X(x/\sigma)/\sigma$ for $\sigma > 0$, then what is the mean and variance of $Y$?

The answer to this question is that $$f_Y(x) = f_X(x/\sigma)/\sigma \tag{1}$$ implies $$Y = \sigma X, \tag{2}$$ hence $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = \sigma \operatorname{E}[X] = 0, \tag{3}$$ and $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \sigma^2 \operatorname{Var}[X] = \sigma^2. \tag{4}$$  We can prove these as follows; for a positive integer $k$,

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[Y^k] &= \int_{y = - \infty}^\infty y^k f_Y(y) \, dy \\
&= \int_{y = -\infty}^\infty y^k f_X(y/\sigma)/\sigma \, dy \\
&= \sigma^{k-1} \int_{y = -\infty}^\infty (y/\sigma)^k f_X(y/\sigma) \, dy \\
&= \sigma^{k-1} \int_{x = -\infty}^\infty x^k f_X(x) \cdot \sigma \, dx & (y = \sigma x, \quad dy = \sigma \, dx) \\
&= \sigma^k \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty x f_X(x) \, dx \\
&= \sigma^k \operatorname{E}[X]. \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

Then $(3)$ immediately follows from the case $k = 1$, and $(4)$ follows from setting $k = 2$ and observing
$$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \operatorname{E}[Y^2] - \operatorname{E}[Y]^2 = \sigma^2 \operatorname{E}[X^2] - (\sigma \operatorname{E}[X])^2 = \sigma^2 (\operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2) = \sigma^2 \operatorname{Var}[X].$$

---

Since it seems you're having problems with understanding the above method, I will show step by step how to compute the second moment explicitly:

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[Y^2] &= \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty y^2 f_Y(y) \, dy \\
&= \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty y^2 f_X(y/\sigma)/\sigma \, dy & \text{since by (1), } f_Y(y) = f_X(y/\sigma)/\sigma \\
&= \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty (\sigma x)^2 f_X(\sigma x/\sigma)/\sigma \cdot \sigma \, dx & \text{substitute } y = \sigma x, \quad dy = \sigma \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \sigma^2 x^2 f_X(x) \, dx \\
&= \sigma^2 \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty x^2 f_X(x) \, dx & \text{factor out the constant} \\
&= \sigma^2 \operatorname{E}[X^2].
\end{align}$$

Since the mean of $X$ is $0$, the variance of $X$ is $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2 = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - 0^2 = \operatorname{E}[X^2];$$ similarly, $\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \operatorname{E}[Y^2]$ since the mean of $Y$ is also $0$ as you already established.  Therefore $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \sigma^2 \operatorname{Var}[X].$$

Comment: Why and how do you justify removing $\sigma$ from the integral as $\sigma^{k-1}$ and not as just $1/\sigma$?  And why does $y^{k}$ become $(y/\sigma)^{k}$?

Comment: $\sigma$ is a constant with respect to integration.  If you don't like this presentation, you can equivalently write (omitting the limits of integration for brevity) $$\int y^k f_X(y/\sigma)/\sigma \, dy = \int (\sigma x)^k f_X(x)/\sigma \cdot \sigma \, dx = \sigma^k \int x^k f_X(x) \, dx,$$ after substituting $y = \sigma x$ and $dy = \sigma \, dx$.

Comment: I was under the impression that you remove the constant outside of the integration.  In this case, the constant is $1/\sigma$.  So I have been operating under the assumption that the integration is multiplied by $1/\sigma$, and yet by the end of this solution, we seem to end up with $\sigma^{k}$.   So my confusion is less that a constant can be removed outside of the integration and more how it changes from $1/\sigma$ to $\sigma^{k}$.

Comment: @StanleyYu It doesn't "change."  The factor $\sigma^k$ arises from the substitution $y = \sigma x$, hence $y^k = (\sigma x)^k = \sigma^k x^k$.  If you prefer, you can just compute $\operatorname{E}[Y]$ and $\operatorname{E}[Y^2]$ directly, without using $k$.